# Spring Boot 2 with Hibernate Search, indexes are not created on save

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin, hibernate-search

I've an entity defined like below. If I use save() Hibernate does not create a new index for newly created entity. Updating/modifying an existing entity works well and as expected.

I'm using kotling with spring boot 2.

```
@Entity(name = "shipment")
@Indexed
data class Shipment(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long = -1,
        @JoinColumn(name = "user") @ManyToOne() var user: User?,
        @IndexedEmbedded
        @JoinColumn(name = "sender") @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) val sender: Contact,
        @IndexedEmbedded
        @JoinColumn(name = "sender_information") @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) val senderInformation: ShipmentInformation,
) {}
```

Save function, I'm using this same function to update my entity and index is updated if index exists.

```
    @Transactional
    fun save(user: User, shipment: Shipment): Shipment {
        shipment.user = user;
        return this.shipmentRepository.save(shipment)
    }
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase=./lucene/
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

If I restart the server, indexing manually works too.

```
    @Transactional
    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ApplicationReadyEvent) {
        val fullTextEntityManager: FullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().purgeAllOnStart(true)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().optimizeAfterPurge(true)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().batchSizeToLoadObjects(15)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().threadsToLoadObjects(2)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().typesToIndexInParallel(2)
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait()
        return
    }
```

I tried to force to use JPA transaction manager but It did not help me.

```
    @Bean(name = arrayOf("transactionManager"))
    @Primary
    fun transactionManager(@Autowired entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory): org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager {
        return JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory)
    }
```

### Update

I think I found why I don't get the results of newly inserted entities.

My search query has a condition on "pid" field which is declared:

```
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
        @SortableField
        @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
        @JsonIgnore
        @NumericField val pid: Long,
```

and query:

```
query.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("customer.pid").matching(user.customer.id.toString()).createQuery())
```

pid is not stored and so newly inserted values are not visible. Can this be the cause?

BTW: How can I query/search by nested indexed document id? In my case it is customer.id which is DocumentId. I've tried to change the query like below but don't get any result, should I create a new field to query?

```
query.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("customer.id").matching(user.customer.id.toString()).createQuery())
```

### Update 2

I found a solution and now getting the newly inserted datas too. There was an error with definition of "pid" field and I've defined my Fields as below and it works as expected.

```
        @Fields(
                Field(name = "pid", index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
        )
        @SortableField(forField = "pid")
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long?,
```

Can we search and sort by id in an easy way or is it the best practice? I know that we should use native JPA functions to get results by id but in my case I need to search by an embedded id to restrict search results. (depends on role of user) so therefore it is not an option for me.

And I don't understand why manual indexing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BTW: How can I query/search by nested indexed document id? In my case it is customer.id which is DocumentId. I've tried to change the query like below but don't get any result, should I create a new field to query?

Normally you don't *need* to create a separate field if all you want is to perform an exact match.

> Can we search and sort by id in an easy way

Searching, yes, at least in Hibernate Search 5.

Sorting, no: you need a dedicated field.

> or is it the best practice?

The best practice is to declare a field alongside your `@DocumentId` if you need anything more complex than an exact match on the ID.

> I know that we should use native JPA functions to get results by id

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "native JPA functions".

> but in my case I need to search by an embedded id to restrict search results. (depends on role of user)

Yes, this should work. That is, it should work if the id is properly populated.

> And I don't understand why manual indexing works...

Neither do I, but I suppose the explanation lies in the "error in the definition of "pid" field". Maybe the ID wasn't populated properly in some cases, leading to the entity being considered as deleted by Hibernate Search?

If you need me to give you a definitive answer, the best way to get it would be to create a reproducer. You can use this as a template: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search

Comment: Many thanks for your very helpful answers. :)
I've a one small question about exact match:

queryBuilder.keyword().onField("customer.id").matching(user.customer.id)
If I use this on @Id field, I don't get any results. Am I building wrong query for an exact match?

Comment: I don't see any "customer" field in your model, so yes this seems wrong. Double check the name of your field?

Answer (score 0):

This looks odd:

```
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long = -1,
```

I'd expect a nullable long, initialized to `null` (or whatever is the Kotlin equivalent).

I'm not sure this is the problem, but I imagine it could be, as a non-null ID is generally only expected from an already persisted entity.

Other than that, I think you're on the right track: if mass indexing works but not automatic indexing, it may have something to do with your changes not being executed in database transactions.

Comment: I chaged it to 
` @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long?` so id is null but I didn't help. 

After saving if I call search function, I'm still getting the results which are indexed at startup. After Server restart, I get the entities including saved new entities.

Comment: And there's nothing in your logs? Could you set the level of the logger "org.hibernate.search" to TRACE, insert a few entities and post the resulting logs to https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nodify-at/4cdefa11c10527b81a4249ee7448bc0a

Thanks, it looks fine with indexing, But Why don't I get this entity without restarting of my server?

Comment: I updated the gist including search logs, expected 11 but it returns 10

Comment: Can you please check my updated question? I think I found why I don't get newly inserted rows.

Comment: Can I find somewhere in Hibernate explanations about my questions? :)